# Anyone willing to share their experience using Sonatype's Procurement feature?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I'm trying to set up a new build environment for my company, and they have strict rules on which licenses they are willing to accept in third party products, and GPL is not on the approved list.

I take it that only very few modules on MavenCentral are GPL, but the possibility exists that some developer might inadvertently insert that dependency.

So I wonder if anyone already did set up a way for SonaType Nexus to filter artifacts by license, and was willing to share insights.

Comment: I'm in the process of reading the "Procurement" section in the Nexus book.

Comment: This question appears to not cover a concrete programming problem, but is rather conceptual. Conceptual questions are better suited on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This sort of policy based process is what [Sonatype CLM](http://www.sonatype.com/clm/overview) implements. There are a couple of useful webinars, presentations and other useful material on the website. Specifically you might be interested in the [recent webinars](http://www.sonatype.com/request/nexus-webinar-series) about the Golden Repository and the [related blog post I wrote](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2013/10/golden-repository).

And of course you could also join us for a Nexus Live event to discuss this more.